# Assembly reference missing in my project

Tags: mono, assemblies, reference

In my project, i need to use this namespaces :

```
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
```

But when I compile, I get an error: `The type or namespace name 'xxx' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Windows'. Are you missing an assembly reference ?`

I tried to add this references but i didn't find in the list.

What can i do ?

Thanks in advance for your reply.

Comment: I guessing you are using Monodevelop? What distribution are you using? Which Mono version? Are you sure you have System.Windows.Forms library installed? (e.g. on Ubuntu it might not be installed, because Monodevelop does not depend on it)

Comment: Yes, i'm using Monodevelop 2.5.90 with mono 2.10.4. I have System.Windows.Forms on Ubuntu. I need to get moonlight i think, no ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The namespaces you are trying to reference are part of WPF libraries (`PresentationFramework.dll`, `PresentationCore.dll`) which are not implemented **at all** by Mono (and [no changes to this are planned so far](http://www.mono-project.com/WPF)). Sorry, but full WPF is not supported - you'll have to stick to just what Silverlight offers.

Comment: Is it still the case? http://go-mono.com/status/status.aspx?reference=4.0&profile=4.5&assembly=PresentationCore suggests it should be implemented now, but I don't understand from which version from that.

Comment: Unfortunately the class status pages are no longer automatically generated (there's a timestamp on top of the page that right now shows '810 days ago'). Last update was just before Mono 2.11.0 was released.